# How use curl in cron to process a URL?

Tags: curl, cron

I have a very simple task. I have a crontab that will run a script every hour. The script is meant to simply process a URL.

This is what I have. It doesn't work. I get a syntax error.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
curl http://example.com/page.html;
```

I haven't worked in Perl in years and wasn't very adept when I did.

**SOLUTION**

Thanks, Alex for pointing me to the correct path!

crontab

```
*/30 * * * * curl http://example.com/path.html
```

Comment: Try enclosing `curl http://domain.com/page.html` in backquotes (the character generally underneath the tilde (~) on the keyboard).

Comment: Am I missing something here? Why are you using Perl? Just run the curl direct from cron.

Comment: The solution you recently added to your question will just cause `curl` to dump the contents of the web page to its stdout, which will then be e-mailed to you.  Is that what you want?  In your original question, you said you want to "simply process a URL"; process it in what way?

Comment: Keith - I noticed that. I have a php web page to grab some XML data and store it in a database. I'm using crontab to get that page so that the php executes and the data is captured. I am open to any suggestions on a better way to automate this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can either use `curl` via backticks

```
my $curl=`curl http://whatever`
```

or you can use [`WWW::Curl`](http://search.cpan.org/~szbalint/WWW-Curl-4.15/lib/WWW/Curl.pm).

Answer (score 5):

To call any shell command from Perl, you can use [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html):

```
system "curl http://domain.com/page.html";
```

Just enclose the shell command in quotes.

Comment: Well, I believe the OP wants to capture and parse the HTML, so calling `system()` won't do the trick, as it'll only return the exit status of the process (shifted 8 bits to account for the child exit status, yada yada...).

Comment: That's true, but the question didn't say that. Sometimes people write scripts to hit a URL every hour to trigger things done on the server side.

Comment: If that's the case then you don't need Perl at all, just run the curl right from cron.

Comment: Far be it from me to say whether or not somebody ought to use Perl to help solve their problem.

Comment: I am not married to using Perl, believe me.

Comment: I went with Alex's idea (once I figured out how to do it). Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If shying away from executing command-line tools from within Perl, the library equivalent is:

```perl
use WWW::Curl::Simple;
my $curl = WWW::Curl::Simple->new();
my $res = $curl->get("https://stackoverflow.com");
```

You would then access the content as in:

```perl
print $res->content;
```

You may want to read [WWW::Curl::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Curl::Simple), where the get method returns an [HTTP::Response](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Response).

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you need to pass multiple parameters.

```
my $cc = 'curl -v -X GET https://base-template.squarespace.com/blog/\?field1=value1\&format=json-pretty\&field3=value3';
print `$cc`;
```