# How to execute CURL command from a perl script?

Tags: spring, perl, curl, optimization, controller

I want to warm up my service as soon as deployment is done, otherwise the first person hitting my service faces a big latency.

For this i want to execute a curl command similar to :

```
curl -v -H "Accept:text/x-html-parts,text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Accept-Charset:UTF-8" -H "Accept-Encoding:identity" -H "Connection:Keep-Alive" -H "Via:HTTP/1.1 ShoppingArea" + + + something.. something....
```

This curl script will execute during the deployment process and will invoke the main spring controller of my service.

I want to write this command in a perl file.

But i am not very sure how to do this!

Any leads would be helpful :)

Comment: Probably better to do it in pure perl... LWP::UserAgent or a similar module. Heck, there might even be a libcurl binding...

Comment: Using https://corion.net/curl2lwp.psgi , you can easily convert a Curl command line to a Perl script using LWP::UserAgent. The comment box is too small for the resulting code, but if that's what you're looking for, I can post it as answer.

Comment: @Corion it would be appreciable if u put it in as an answer upfront! :)

Comment: `curl` is just a wrapper for the libcurl library. Rather than shelling out, why not use the libcurl library directly? [Net::Curl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::Curl).

Answer (score 3):

As a rough prototype of reproducing what `curl` does in pure Perl (Using https://corion.net/curl2lwp.psgi ), you can easily convert a Curl command line to a Perl script using LWP::UserAgent:

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request;


my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $r  = HTTP::Request->new(
    'GET' => 'https://api.example.com/',
    [
        'Connection' => 'Keep-Alive',
        'Via'        => 'HTTP/1.1 ShoppingArea',
        'Accept' =>
'text/x-html-parts,text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Charset'  => 'UTF-8',
        'Accept-Encoding' => 'identity',
        'Host'            => 'api.example.com:443',
        'User-Agent'      => 'curl/7.55.1',
    ],

);
my $res = $ua->request( $r, );


__END__

Created from curl command line
curl -v -H "Accept:text/x-html-parts,text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Accept-Charset:UTF-8" -H "Accept-Encoding:identity" -H "Connection:Keep-Alive" -H "Via:HTTP/1.1 ShoppingArea" https://api.example.com/
```

This requires the [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) module, so shelling out to `curl` might still be a quicker approach to you. If you need to react on the result, like sending error mails on HTTP Error 500 or other notifications on HTTP Error 4xx, using pure Perl is more convenient as you get the status code directly back.

Comment: while i am trying to run the above script,
i get " java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens" as an error.

i guess this is due to presence of "|" (pipe) character. how can i get rid of this?

Comment: That is a Java error message. Where do you get that Java error message from? The above script is a Perl script.

Comment: thanks for the help!
can you please let me know, how can i be sure that this script got executed successfully or not?

Comment: @GauravSetia This is more a debugging question - I don't know how to debug Java scripts, but you can `print $res->is_success` or `exit $res->is_success` or `print $res->code` to see/signal the request status.

Answer (score 1):

Bad practice, but using `system` (runs arbitrary shell code):

```
system "curl -v -H 'Accept:text/x-html-parts,text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Charset:UTF-8' -H 'Accept-Encoding:identity' -H 'Connection:Keep-Alive' -H 'Via:HTTP/1.1 ShoppingArea' + + + something.. something...."
```

also, from ([How do I write a Perl script to use curl to process a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196124/how-do-i-write-a-perl-script-to-use-curl-to-process-a-url)):

```
my $curl=`curl http://whatever`
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use specific CURL only in your Perl Script. I would Recommend you to execute System call using backticks.

```
my $curlcomm = `curl -v -H "Accept:text/x-html-parts,text/html,application/xhtml+xml,applicatio/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Accept-Charset:UTF-8" -H "Accept-Encoding:identity" -H "Connection:Keep-Alive" -H "Via:HTTP/1.1 ShoppingArea" + + + something.. something....`
```

but standard ways are also available that can be using [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent), [LWP::Curl](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Curl) and similar.